# Can't set 'Force Secure URLs'

Tags: admin

Civi 4.4 still w/WP 4.7 (which is using https/secure URLs w/a plugin 'https') - I tried setting base url to 'www.mysite.org' as opposed to 'mysite.org' and saving but my change isn't saved.
FYI I am using https: in effect for all civi pages, but I can't seem to set this in Admin settings.  My .htaccess file allows for www or not

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly want to upgrade your version of CiviCRM at least to 4.6, due to security concerns.

If you're already forcing https for all Civi pages via WP (or via apache/.htaccess, or any other mechanism), then there's no point in setting it in CiviCRM.

The base url setting is likely hard-coded into your civicrm.settings.php file, you'll want to change it there.

In general, having a consistent version of your domain is a good thing, for lots of reasons (SEO and caching are the two main ones).

Comment: Mainly I want to force ssl, and I put that in my .htaccess file to be sure.  I have seen some discussion re: using subdomain 'www' but I find it more of an annoyance and didn't set up the base url that way.  And yes, I want to/plan to upgrade, when I move to another host.